# More colloquial term for "aggregating operations/functions"?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

i.e. Sum, mean, median, mode...

"Aggregate function" a really awkward phrase to say, is there a more elegant term for this? Given google gives minimal results for this term, I imagine it is not the preferred term, but I also couldn't find the preferred term.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function

Comment: Consider statistic

Comment: In lisp (where just about everything is a function) or other programming languages it might be called simply an aggregator. We might be able to help more if you [edit] the question to tell us the context where you need this word.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific context, I'm wondering if there's a conventional term that I don't know about used by the wider community.

Comment: Sadly, people who seek to establish technical terminology, seldom seem to consider 'elegance' as a criterion.